# Using NLog with ModernUI on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, nlog

Is it possible to use NLog with Windows 8.1 applications.

I have installed NLog using Nuget.  After adding NLog to References I have the error:

`Can not find type System.Collections.CollectionBase in module mscorelib.dll`

If it is not possible which logger can you recommend for windows 8.1 applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Collections.CollectionBase is not a supported namespace in WinRT:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454064.aspx

There are a couple of solutions, neither of which I've used so I can't personally recommend, but you can try out:

1) https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Logging-Sample-for-Windows-0b9dffd7
2) https://github.com/mbrit/MetroLog